# count of diferent values with the same id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, distinct

I have ID_employe in one column (the same ID can be on more than 2 rows) and in other column I have ID_job.

I need MYSQL to find same values in the first column and then check, if there are everytime the same values in the second column.

If there is any difference, I need to give me number of ID_employe what has it different.

So example:

[image]

from this example I need SQL to give me result: 2
(because ID_employe 1 and 3 has different ID_job)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

With `EXISTS`:

```
select count(distinct t.ID_employe) counter
from tablename t
where exists (select 1 from tablename where ID_employe = t.ID_employe and ID_job <> t.ID_job)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `having` clause and compare the minimum and maximum `id_job` per `id_employee` to exhibit those that have at least two jobs. Then you can count in another level of aggregation:

```
select count(*) cnt
from (
    select id_employee
    from mytable
    group by id_employee
    having min(id_job) <> max(id_job)
) t
```